# How to add an updated timestamp in JSX/React JS when user clicks add button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I have been working on a simple task manager program that adds tasks to a list and prints each item to the webpage when the user clicks an add button.  I got this part working fine, but now I am wanting to add a timestamp that automatically updates next to the tasks to be printed from within the webpage. So for example, after the user enters a string into the input box, such as `complete project`, and clicks add, instead of printing `complete project`, it would print, `10/03/2018, 3:25:00 PM, complete project`.

As can be seen from my `addItem` method below, I can get the timestamp to print to the console, along with the correct format. My question is, what do I need to do to do to get this to print correctly to the webpage in my `App.js` render function listed below? Any help with this would be appreciated (NOTE: I don't know if this is relevant to answering this issue, but at the bottom of the page, I have also listed the `TodoItems.js` component that I have referenced in my `App.js` render function, which is creating the tasks).

Here is the `App.js` addItem function.

```
 //add items to the list on click
  addItem(e) {
    var itemArray = this.state.items;
    const timestamp = Date.now();

    if (this._inputElement.value !== "") {    
      itemArray.unshift(
        {      
          text: this._inputElement.value,      
          key: Date.now()    
        }
      );

      this.setState({      
        items: itemArray    
      });   

      this._inputElement.value = "";  
    }   
    console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(timestamp),itemArray);   

    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

And here is my `App.js` render function (so far, I have been trying to change things from within the "taskContainer" div in the middle of this code.

```
render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <nav className="navbar pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">

          <img src="/vandelay_industries.jpeg" alt="img" width="128" height="120" ></img>

        <a href="#" className="pure-menu-heading pure-menu-link">File Upload DApp Using IPFS</a>
        </nav>

        <main className="container">
          <div className="pure-g">
            <div className="pure-u-1-1">

             <div className="taskContainer">
                   <form onSubmit={this.addItem} >     
                      <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a}  
                        placeholder="Enter comments">

                    </input>            
                     <button type="submit">add</button>  
                       </form>  
                        <TodoItems entries={this.state.items} 

                  delete={this.deleteItem}/> 
              </div>

              <h1>Image</h1>
              <p>This image will be stored on IPFS & The Ethereum Blockchain</p>
              <img src={`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${this.state.ipfsHash}`} alt=""/>
              <h2>Upload Image</h2>
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                <input type='file' onChange={this.captureFile} />
                <input type='submit' />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`TodoItems.js` component

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import FlipMove from 'react-flip-move';

//another component that takes care of the creating and deleting the tasks as
// We have to import this into app.js
//for this to be in scope.
class TodoItems extends Component {  
  constructor(props) {    
    super(props);     
    this.createTasks = this.createTasks.bind(this);  
  }   

  delete(key){     
    this.props.delete(key);  
  }

  createTasks(item) {    
    return <li onClick={() => this.delete(item.key)} key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>
  }   

  render() {    
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;    
    var listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);  

    return (      
      <ul className="theList">
        <FlipMove duration={250} easing="ease-out">      
          {listItems} 
        </FlipMove>   
      </ul>
      );  
    }
  } 

  export default TodoItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you console.log. Set it to the state by doing

`this.setState({date: new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(timestamp),itemArray}});`

Later you should be able to use the:

```
this.state.date
```

Inside your render function.

Comment: I will try this. My apologies if this is a bad question, but just to clarify, so I put "this.setState..." that you mentioned above from within my console.log statement? I have a this.setState within the addItem function but that is for the itemsArray I am using. I am unsure where to put this.setState for the date.

Comment: For a good start place it right after the console statement. What's going to happen is: React re-renders the component every time you call the setState method. When you set it after the console.log, it will call the render method that will print out the value you set in the state.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. The page goes blank and won't render the template. So is it storing the date in the list in my application? Is there any way to just put the date within the list/array also so that both are printed? I don't know if that would be too complicated or not.

Comment: After a while, I figured it out. If you add Date.now() after text: this._inputElement.value, then it works. So the line complete line of code would be the following: text: this._inputElement.value + Date.now()

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple. If you include the the timestamp after the input statement, then it prints to the webpage. Here is the updated addItem(e) method with the additions:

```
addItem(e) {
    var itemArray = this.state.items; 

    let timestamp = new Date();
    let date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(timestamp)

    if (this._inputElement.value !== "") {    
      itemArray.unshift(
        { 
          text: this._inputElement.value + " " + date,      
          key: Date.now()  
        }

      );

      this.setState({      
        items: itemArray 
      }); 

      this._inputElement.value = "";  
    }   

    //console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(timestamp),itemArray);   
    console.log(new Date(),itemArray);   

    this.setState({date: new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(timestamp)});

    e.preventDefault();
  }
```